# I need a function that converts a permutation to its transposition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, functions, permutations

If I have the permutation: $(a, b, c,..., n)$ how do I find the transposition of this? (AKA the number of "swaps" to get from this: $(1, 2, 3,..., N)$ to that: $(a, b, c,..., n)$.

So:

$f(3, 2, 1) = (13)$

$f(5, 3, 4, 2, 1) = (15)(23)(24)$

$f(8, 6, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3, 1) = (18)(26)(25)(27)(23)(24)$

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Note - I know that $(15)(23)(24)$ can be written as $(15)(234)$ but I would prefer the former so I can easily tell if the permutation is even or odd.

Comment: by function you mean an algorithm?

Comment: your ultimate goal is to find a factorization or just the parity?

Comment: I don't think there is a good/clever algorithm to find the cycle structure from the $(a,b,c,...,n)$ notation. You can always find it by tracing the paths one by one. Working with permutations is much easier when they come to you in cycle notation.

Answer (score 2):

Note that every permutation can be written as the product of distinct cycles & each cycle can be written as the product of transpositions as follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1234 \cdots n) =(12)(13)(14) \cdots (1n).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Correct, of course. but I don't think it answers the OP's (not quite clear) question. I suspect s/he wants to find the parity when the permutation is given as a list.